# VB Simple Form To Update Database Using SqlCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have one field form that has an editor and I'm trying to update my database. I can populate the form data and decode it for display but I'm unable to get it to update. The code below is from my submit button and I'm doing two things encode the content and save it to the database. I'm not getting any errors just a page refresh. The syntax as far as I've found looks right.

In the example below the "CKEditorControl1" is my WYSIWYG text editor. It outputs html which I'm attempting to encode and save.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim section = Page.Request.Params("SectionName")

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    conn.Open()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE PageContent SET SectionBody = @SectionBody WHERE SectionName = @SectionName", conn)

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionName", section.ToString())
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionBody", Server.HtmlEncode(CKEditorControl1.Text))

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use `AddWithValue("@SectionBody", Server.HtmlEncode(CKEditorControl1.Text))` and also  `command.Parameters("@SectionBody").Value=Server.HtmlEncode(CKEditorControl1.Text)`. Not that this should be a problem but one of both is redundant. Have you used the debugger?

Comment: If you are not getting an error, I assume `WHERE SectionName = @SectionName` is not getting the right string, and therfore not finding a row to update. run a `msgBox(section.ToString())` to see.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I honestly didn't see a difference from each but didn't know if one was preferred over the other for an update. I updated my sample. The debugger doesn't give me much of a clue since the page just refreshes.

Comment: @Cory I was pretty positive that the section param was there but just to check it with the message box showed it is there. I"m not sure what would be next to try.

Comment: So if I swap out the editor for a textbox it works. So the odd thing is I can't get the current value of the editor and submit that as encoded html to the database.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that my submit code had nothing wrong with it from the start. The issue was how I was populating the editor control from the beginning which was on page load. On postback to update the page load was preventing the update from happening from the editor. For a textbox control the postback didn't effect it. When I did a trace of the updated content on submit between the textbox and the editor I saw the postback was in fact the issue. A little if statement in my page load to prevent the post back from overwriting my update to populate the form and presto.